# Laravel Lumen : execute mysql function with insert into

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I'm looking to execute a custom **MySQL function** in a query in order to update (or insert) a value in database.

My actual code (with custom query) :

```
DB::statement('INSERT INTO locations(longitude, latitude, altitude, speed, point, user_id, circle)
                    VALUES (' . $long . ', ' . $lat . ', ' . $alt . ', ' . $speed . ', ' . $point . ', GETPOLYGON(' . $lat . ', ' . $long . ' , 0.300, 12))
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE longitude=' . $long . ',latitude=' . $lat . ',altitude=' . $alt . ',speed=' . $speed . ',point=' . $point . ',circle=GETPOLYGON(' . $lat . ', ' . $long . ' , 0.300, 12)');
```

I don't really know if execute like this is the best way in my case.

My custom function is 'getpolygon'. But it doesn't seem to work

```
[2020-04-17 08:23:01] local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '43.325178, GETPOLYGON(43.325178, 1.121354 , 0.300, 12))
```

My function in SQL :

```
CREATE FUNCTION getpolygon(lat DOUBLE, lon DOUBLE, radius SMALLINT, corner TINYINT) RETURNS geometry DETERMINISTIC BEGIN DECLARE i TINYINT DEFAULT 1; DECLARE a, b, c DOUBLE; DECLARE res TEXT; IF corner < 3 || radius > 500 THEN RETURN NULL; END IF; SET res = CONCAT(lat + radius / 111.12, ' ', lon, ','); WHILE i < corner  do SET c = RADIANS(360 / corner * i); SET a = lat + COS(c) * radius / 111.12; SET b = lon + SIN(c) * radius / (COS(RADIANS(lat + COS(c) * radius / 111.12 / 111.12)) * 111.12); SET res = CONCAT(res, a, ' ', b, ','); SET i = i + 1; END WHILE; RETURN GEOMFROMTEXT(CONCAT('POLYGON((', res, lat + radius / 111.12, ' ', lon, '))')); END;
```

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give user_id value. The problem can be from it?

Comment: You declared the radius parameter as small int and pass a float...

Comment: Also you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection vulnerability

Comment: @Furkanöztürk indeed, this issue (missing 1 parameter) is fixed but it don't resolve my issue (thanks for it !)

Comment: @EliasSoares Indeed, I fix this issue (my bad). If I use 'DB::insert' with laravel, can I insert the result of my mysql function as the value of a column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few errors here as commented in the question.

1. Your function expects `radius` to be `SMALLINT`, but you are passing a float value to it.
2. You are missing `user_id` in values, so the actual code puts the output of your function `getpolygon()` to `user_id` column, and nothing into `circle` column, leading to a syntax error.
3. Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection. I said *probably* because I don't know the source of the variables that you concatenate on the query.

So, to fix the SQL Injection, you can use prepared statements with `DB::statement($query, $bindings)` (see [API Docs](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_statement)):

```
DB::statement(
    'INSERT INTO locations(longitude, latitude, altitude, speed, point, user_id, circle)
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, GETPOLYGON(?,?, 0.300, 12))
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE longitude=?,latitude=?,altitude=?,speed=?,point=?,user_id=?,circle=GETPOLYGON(?,?, 0.300, 12)',
    [
        $long, $lat, $alt, $speed, $point, $user_id, $lat, $long,
        $long, $lat, $alt, $speed, $point, $user_id, $lat, $long,
    ]
);
```

Note that the params are added twice since you need to bind into insert and update statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The two first steps was OK after two responses to my post. And so, my custom functions in SQL will be executed and the returned value is going to fill the 'circle' column, right ?

Comment: Yes, just as your original query, but now sql injection safe. Please accept my answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: Another error was using 'GEOMFROMTEXT' instead of 'ST_GEOMFROMTEXT' (right way so far)